# Whats the difference between unwittingly and inadvertantly?

Tags: differences

Are those words pure synonyms or is there any difference? What would be the most obvious usage of those words?

Comment: For all intents and purposes, they are synonyms. But _"pure synonym"_ is sorta like _perfect sphere_ — "_virtually nonexistent"_. There's difference still between them.

Comment: They could be used interchangeably, but they are subtly different in sense. Compare ***not knowingly*** (*unwittingly*) to ***without attention*** (*inadvertantly*).

Comment: If you do something ***unwittingly***, you definitely weren't aware that you were doing it. But there's no such implication with something done ***inadvertently*** - maybe you noticed, maybe you didn't; it's "agnostic" on that point. All we know is you didn't do it *deliberately* (with the strong implication that if you'd been able to *avoid* doing it, you would have). Any dictionary should make this distinction clear.

Answer (score 1):

Inadvertently is a synonym of unwittingly in that they refer to an unintentional act. Unwittingly also has the denotation that one is unaware of the act.

> : not knowing : UNAWARE
> kept the truth from their unwitting friends

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unwitting)

This may be too fine a line for a reader to see in many contexts.

Answer (score 1):

I think the difference comes down to implicit meaning.

"Unwittingly" to me implies a lack of wit, as if the accident was caused by someone who isn't very intelligent.

"Inadvertently" is more of a true "accident", at least, that's how it sounds to me.

Comment: Unwitting is not about intelligence, it's about not doing something on  purpose...,

Comment: From OED: unwitting (adj.)
late 14c., altered from or re-formed to replace unwitand, from Old English unwitende "ignorant".   "Ignorant" and "lacking wit" are similar in meaning, are they not?

Comment: _Unwitting_ comes from an Old English word meaning _not knowing_ rather than the modern _wit_ meaning intelligence.